# Are these statements equivalent?: import package vs from package import *

Tags: python, python-2.7

Are these statements equivalent?:

`import math` and `from math import *`

Comment: One pollutes your namespace, the other does not.  Is this homework?

Comment: ...try them and see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import math` means that you have to put the `math` (name of the module) before everything you use from it, e.g. `print(math.pi)`.

With using `from math import *`, Python is loading all functions and variables from `math` (or those specified in `__all__` to be exact) into you local namespace and you can use them without module name prefix: `print(pi)`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @cdarke You're right, but it seems he's a beginner and not might have gone so deep into Python so far...

Comment: @cdarke Updated the answer :)